# Intellij ignorance on .kt files under package structure having no 'package ..' statement? WHY?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

```
package com.yada.yada
```

What happens with IntelliJ when I create Java class 'ss' in `com.yada.yada` without package statement? - RED "Missing Package Statement".

What happens when I create Kotlin file in `com.yada.yada` without package statement? - "Keep going bro until your DI framework will fail to scan your deps during runtime"

**Why IJ package validation is non-mandatory for Kotlin? I just wasted an hour trying to figure out what's wrong with package scan only to realise this was the show stopper. Would Java 9 jigsaw quadruple the chaos for Kotlin sparked by such malformed files/classes with no warning messages? Well, you bet it will!**

Please return back the "warning" statement for Kotlin. P.S. registration/login methods are not sufficient for myself to access Intellij bugtracker(and I am genuinely pissed off with one time access password resets, 1000 resources and 980 passwords I don't remember or care to) therefore making this public on stackoverflow.

If anybody going to defend this behaviour please explain why? Maybe I am missing something, otherwise please reply with open bug(preferably somebody from JetBrains) and I will accept it.

Comment: Can't you open a bug ticket yourself? It is very easy: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT. After all, you are the only one who knows all the details of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing inspection warning for files with no package statement is a bug; the corresponding YouTrack issue is [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13549).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this post is appropriate here, but to answer the actual question, the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html) states that:

> If the package is not specified, the contents of such a file belong to
>   "default" package that has no name.

Since with Kotlin your files don't have to be in folders that match their packages, not having a package declaration has to be an option so that you can have files that are organized in folders, but you don't wish to put them in packages - this way they can have the same package as if they weren't nested in any folders, and were just in the root of the project.

I do concede that it's a bit odd there is a warning for your package declaration not matching the folder your file is in, but you don't get this if you just omit the package declaration altogether. I suppose this is assumed to be intentional.

This shouldn't generally be a problem because IDEs will generate the appropriate package declaration for the folder you've created your file in by default. I'm not sure how you created a file without a package declaration if you're using IntelliJ, unless you did it in the root `src` folder instead of inside a package folder.

Comment: Nobody argues with behavior of default packages, what I am complaining about is loooong defined standard IJ warning which is missed in Kotlin. Dmitrii just confirmed that this is not intentional in his answer. The issue happened to me when I was copying around the files from another project, I expect some basic such as this one to be done automatically as it always was in Java.